# Twitter Bootstrap Carousel in Wordpress not automatically starting

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am trying to get a website running on Wordpress, with a customised Twitter Bootstrap theme.

I have been looking around at similar problems with their answers, but I can't seem to make the carousel on the homepage start automatically. It will start sliding after I click on the left/right arrows, but I think there is still something wrong because even though I set the slide interval to 500, it does not appear to be so. I guess it must be something very basic that I am missing.

Is it the sequence of the scripts that I am loading (related to functions.php):

```
<?php 
function wpbootstrap_scripts_with_jquery()
{
    // Register the script like this for a theme:
    wp_register_script( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    // For either a plugin or a theme, you can then enqueue the script:
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpbootstrap_scripts_with_jquery' );

if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') )
    register_sidebar(array(
        'before_widget' => '',
        'after_widget' => '',
        'before_title' => '<h3>',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ));
?>
```

How about the

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>
```

part in header.php?

Or simply a fundamental error in

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#myCarousel').carousel({
        interval: 500
        });

        $('#myCarousel').carousel('cycle');

    });

</script>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to load `bootstrap.js` before being able to call `carousel()` in your inline script.

```
<script src="http://thirdwavepower.com/V2/wp-content/themes/wpbootstrap/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js?ver=3.5.2"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#myCarousel').carousel({
            interval: 500
        }); 
        $('#myCarousel').carousel('cycle');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can I just check, I tried adding this line of code previously without the "?ver=3.5.2" behind bootstrap.js. The file is not labeled as such, so why does adding this work?

Comment: That is what wordpress adds to your files if you don't provide anything for the `$version` parameter within (it's the version of your WP installation) `wp_register_script()` -  you can instead use `null` if you don't want it appearing at the end of a file name - e.g. `wp_register_script( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js', array( 'jquery' ), null, false)`

Comment: Hi Adrift, I just noticed that dropdown menus are not working after implementation of above. Would you be able to identify if there is some conflict in functions.php?

Comment: You're loading `bootstrap.js` and `jquery.js` twice in your `<head>` - they should only be loaded once. If you hardcoded the new external script files above your inline script, just delete them and move your inline script towards the end of your `<head>`

Comment: hmm I removed the two lines loading jquery.js and bootstrap.js, and now the scripts in <head> looks like this: `<?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>
    
 <?php wp_head(); ?>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myCarousel').carousel({
  interval: 4500
  });
  
  $('#myCarousel').carousel('cycle');

 });
 
 </script>`

Comment: Replace the `$` with `jQuery` in your inline script and it should work, e.g. `<script> jQuery(document).ready(function(){ {jQuery('#myCarousel').carousel({ interval: 4500 }); jQuery('#myCarousel').carousel('cycle); }); </script>`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need to put the JavaScript file after the carousal. Actually before the end of the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
$(document).ready(function() { 
$('#myCarousel').carousel({ interval: 3000, cycle: true });
});
```

Ref: http://twitterbootstrap.org/twitter-bootstrap-3-carousel-not-automatically-starting/

thanks